# Find strings in a large file and write each one to a second file in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (And programming generally).  To make a work project easier, I am trying to write some code that searches an XML file for certain tags and copies the contents to a second file.  The file I need to read from is about 165MB, and will have 10s of thousands of entries to pull out.

I have successfully made it work for small files (Working from example code on forums such as this one), but it falls apart above a certain size (It starts copying large portions of the XML, instead of just the required strings).  I imagine this is because of how I have defined my variables.

Can someone give me a pointer or sample code, to fix this?  I'm surprised it works as far as it does!

This is the code I have now:

```
text = open("UPC_Small.xml", "r")

lines = text.read()

fo = open("output.log", "wt")

crid1 = 0

while True:

    crid1 = lines.find('<ProgramInformation programId="crid://bds.tv/',crid1)
    crid2 = lines.find('">',crid1)
    crid_string = (lines[crid1+45:crid2])

    if crid1 == -1:
        fo.write("End of File")
        fo.close()
        break

    title1 = lines.find('<Title xml:lang="EN" type="main">',crid2)
    title2 = lines.find('</Title>',title1)
    title_string = (lines[title1+33:title2])

    genre1 = lines.find('<Name xml:lang="EN">',title2)
    genre2 = lines.find('</Name>',genre1)
    genre_string = (lines[genre1+20:genre2])

    fo.write(crid_string + "|" + title_string + "|" + genre_string + "\n")
```

Comment: Try a SAX parser. It won’t misparse your XML and should still be reasonably fast and memory-efficient.

Comment: Looks like this is a good Python approach that @minitech mentioned: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html

Comment: `read()` is reading the entire file into memory. That's not going to work for very large files. Instead, consider reorganizing your program to read one line at a time, using `readline()`.

Comment: Maybe it starts to copy large chunks of XML because the `<Title>` and `<Name>` properties are not always in the same order? Also agreed with @pburka, `read` will struggle with big files. `readlines` is better.

Comment: @pburka When you're looking at 165MB it'll actually be fastest to pull it all into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for iterating over XML.

```
def parse_file(filename):
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for program_information in root.findall('ProgramInformation'):
        attr = program_information.attrib
        title = program_information.find('Title').text
        genre = program_information.get('Name').text
        yield attr, title, genre

for attr, title, genre in parse_file("UPC_Small.xml"):
    print attr, title, genre
```

P.S. This code is untested, I have never used the library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to get you on rails to try the SAX parser. For simple parsing and
big files it is better than ElementTree because it consumes less memory.

```
import xml.sax
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class MySaxHandler(ContentHandler):
  def __init__(self):
    ContentHandler.__init__(self)

    self.results = []

  def startElement(self, name, attrs):
    if name == 'ProgramInformation':
      program_id = attrs["programId"]
      self.results.append([program_id, "", ""])

  def characters(self, content):
    self.last_contents = str(content)

  def endElement(self, name):
    if name == 'Title':
      self.results[-1][1] = self.last_contents
    elif name == 'Name':
      self.results[-1][2] = self.last_contents

def parse(filename):
  handler = MySaxHandler()
  xml.sax.parse(filename, handler)
  return handler.results

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fo = open("output.log", "wt")
  fo.write("\n".join("|".join(parse("UPC_Small.xml")))
```